# Reg Ex URL downloaded from email not working on some urls

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

What I am trying to do is download emails using the pop3 protocol using Python, on the whgole it is working fine, i am able to parse all urls from the emails except 1 type:

```
def pop3_downloader(username, password, pop3server, port, use_ssl):
    try:
        server = ''
        if use_ssl == "no":
            server = poplib.POP3(pop3server, port)
        elif use_ssl == "yes":
            server = poplib.POP3_SSL(pop3server, port)
        else:
            pass

        server.user(username)
        server.pass_(password)
        numMessages = len(server.list()[1])

        print("--> # Of Messages: " + str(numMessages))

        email_container = []
        for i in range(numMessages) :
            (server_msg, body, octets) = server.retr(i+1)
            for j in body:
                try:
                    msg = email.message_from_string(j.decode("utf-8"))
                    email_body = msg.get_payload()
                    email_extract_urls = re.findall(r'http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+', email_body)
                    if len(email_extract_urls) > 0:
                        #activation_links = "/activate/|registration.activate&token="
                        #if any(s in email_extract_urls for s in activation_links.split('|')):
                        email_container.append(email_extract_urls)
                except:
                    pass
            #server.dele(i+1)
        server.quit()
        return email_container

    except Exception as e: 
        print_exception()
```

Above is my current code, the email url type that is not being extracted is:

```
http://thesite.com/index.php?option=com_users&task=registration.activate&token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

My regex just ignores this structure but extracts every other type, is there something i am doing wrong here? i have tested a few i have found on various sites but they all seem to fail.

any help is appreciated.

Comment: try taking things that might offend the regex out, then once you figure it out... try to add it to the regex

Comment: actually it worked for me:

`re.findall(r'http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+', "http://thesite.com/index.php?option=com_users&task=registration.activate&token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")`
['http://thesite.com/index.php?option=com_users&task=registration.activate&token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx']